# Any reason not to use @ symbol in web directory name

Tags: security, url, url-encoding

Is there any reason why a person should avoid using the @ symbol in a folder name on their web server?

For example: www.mywebsite.com/@directory/index.php

Comment: possible confusion with email addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Totally not answering the question, just adding some information.

[RFC 2068 (HTTP) section 3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-3.2.1) states that `@` is explicitly allowed in the path part:

```
      URI            = ( absoluteURI | relativeURI ) [ "#" fragment ]
      relativeURI    = net_path | abs_path | rel_path
      abs_path       = "/" rel_path
      rel_path       = [ path ] [ ";" params ] [ "?" query ]
      path           = fsegment *( "/" segment )
      fsegment       = 1*pchar
      segment        = *pchar
      pchar          = uchar | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+"
```

Comment: "But escaping these is only necessary in the query and fragment parts" From what do you conclude that? As I understand your quote both `query` and `fragment` may contain `reserved` characters.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. How stupid of me. A query string without `=` in it would be pretty useless, too... I'll delete that bit.

Answer (score 2):

@ in URI means basic authentication. For example this:

http://www.yahoo.com:80-q=basic+authentication@www.google.com/search?q=basic+authentication

might look like a Yahoo search but is actually a Google search.